# Not able to find xpath. Chropath message - This element might be inside iframe from different src. Currently ChroPath doesn't support for them

Tags: selenium

Below is the HTML snippet I am trying to get xpath. I have tried so many combination in chrome dev tools but no luck. Chropath message is that element might be from different src.
I am not sure what it means. Any help appreciated.

```
<input type="text" class="sn-global-typeahead-input -global-active-input" name="sncwsgs- 
typeahead-input" id="sncwsgs-typeahead-input" placeholder="Search Global" autocomplete="off" 
aria-label="Search" aria-hidden="false" aria-expanded="true" aria-activedescendant="sncwsgs- 
typeahead-record-1-2" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-owns="sncwsgs-typeahead-sections" aria- 
controls="sncwsgs-typeahead-sections" aria-describedby="sncwsgs-typeahead-instructions" aria- 
haspopup="listbox" value="" role="combobox">
```

Comment: are you working with selenium python? and can u confirm the url?

Comment: Yes I am using selenium python. i cant share url as it is internal

Comment: can u share the html code in here?

Comment: <input type="text" class="sn-global-typeahead-input -global" name="sncwsgs-typeahead-input" id="sncwsgs-typeahead-input" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" aria-label="Search" aria-hidden="false" aria-expanded="true" aria-activedescendant="sncwsgs-typeahead-record-0-0" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-owns="sncwsgs-typeahead-sections" aria-controls="sncwsgs-typeahead-sections" aria-describedby="sncwsgs-typeahead-instructions" aria-haspopup="listbox" value="RITM2458982" role="combobox">

Comment: I need to know if this element is inside an iframe

Answer (score 0):

There's an `id` tag, so you can use the following for the XPath:

```py
"//input[@id='sncwsgs-typeahead-input']"
```

That also translates to the following CSS Selector:

```py
"input#sncwsgs-typeahead-input"
```

But if that's inside an `iframe`, you'll need to switch to the iframe first before you can interact with elements inside of it.

Learn about switching into iframes here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/

Example of switching into an `iframe`:

```py
driver.switch_to.frame("iframe")
```

Comment: Already tried various xpath options including above but nothing worked.